# Solr Data Import Handler for Html

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

**TLDR**

How do I configure solr Data Import Handler so it will import html similar to solr's "post" utility ?

**Context**

We're doing a small project where code will export a set pages from wiki/confluence to 'straight html' (for availability in a DR data center--straight html pages will not depend on a database, etc)

We want to index the html pages in solr.

We "have it working" using the solr-shipped "post utility"

```
post -c OPERATIONS -recursive -0 -host solr $(find . -name '*.html')
```

This is fine.....*However*, we would like to leverage the Data Import Handler (DIH), i.e. replace the shell command with a single http call to the DIH endpoint ('/dataimport')

**Question**

How do I configure the tika "data config xml" file to get "similar functionality" as the solr "post command" ?

- when I configure with data-config.xml, solr document only ends up with an "id" and "version" fields (i.e. where id is the untokenized file name)

*correction*: i had originally wrote '"id" and "title" field..."'

```
        "id":"database_operations_2019.html",
        "_version_":1650836000296927232},
```

- however when I use "bin/post" the document has these fields, i.e. including tokenized title:

```
"id":"/usr/local/html/OPERATIONS_2019_1119_1500/./database_operations_2019.html",
        "stream_size":[54115],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["text/html"],
        "dc_title":["Database Operations 2019 Guidebook"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type_hint":["text/html; charset=UTF-8"],
        "resourcename":["/usr/local/html/OPERATIONS_2019_1119_1500/./database_operations_2019.html"],
        "title":["Database Operations 2019 Guidebook"],
        "content_type":["text/html; charset=UTF-8"],
        "_version_":1650834641083432960},
```

**Some Points**

- I've tried RTM'ing, but do not follow how "field" maps to the "html body"
- Parsing a directory-full-ofHTML is a circa-1999 problem, so I don't expect a lot of people
- I've looked at the SimplePostTool.java (implementation of bin/post)...no real anwer.

**Data Config Xml File**

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="file" processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
        dataSource="null"
        htmlMapper="true"
        format="html"
            baseDir="/usr/local/var/www/confluence/OPERATIONS"
        fileName=".*html"
            rootEntity="false">

      <field column="file" name="id"/>

      <entity name="html" processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
              url="${file.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">

        <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
        <field column="dc:format" name="format" meta="true"/>

        <field column="text" name="text"/>

      </entity>

    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: Do you actually get the title in your example? You wrote that you do, but it's not included - and the file name is the `id` field (which _should_ be a raw string, and not a tokenized text string). You can also use the LogTransformer in your configuration to get extended logging for the data import handler.

Comment: My error. I meant "id and version"..I've updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a few lines of code to parse the html files (jsoup) and ditched the solr data import handler (DIH).

Very straightforward using Spring and solr and jsoup html parser.

One caveat: my java "bean" object to store the solr fields needed a "*text*" field for the out-of-the-box default-search-field to work (i.e. with the solr docker instance)

Comment: clarify my java bean needed a field named underscore-text-underscore ...("text" string wrapped in underscores) for the default search field to work correctly.